# Java initializing iVars outside the scope of any method

Tags: java

New to Java, and I am a little confused about this piece of code:

```
public class CitiesDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
}
```

client is being initialized outside the scope of any method. What does this exactly mean? Does each instance of CititiesDialog have a separate client object? Or is this some sort of static/class variable ?

And lastly, is this the norm in Java? to initialize variables outside the scope of constructors/methods, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`client` is an instance variable of `CitiesDialog`

every `CitiesDialog` that you make is going to have it's own `client`.

That kind of initialization is just for when you first make an instance of your class.  you can change `client` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal to see in Java.

What you see here is `private AsyncHttpClient`, which is by itself just a class variable.

Then you see the declaration `new AsyncHttpClient()`, which gets assigned to `client`. This will happen for every new object that gets created.

To address whether this is the norm? I think yes, a common use case is lists, it is best to initialize them as early as possible:

```
public class A {
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This will prevent that you get a `NPE` at a later point, because you have forgotten to declare the list.

One other thing that also helps is to declare the field `final` if it should never be changed after assignment, then it is also ensured by the compiler that the field gets initialized either in the declaration or in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Does each instance of CititiesDialog have a separate client object?

Yes, since it is not marked as `static`.

> is this the norm in Java? to initialize variables outside the scope of constructors/methods, etc...

It's not abnormal, especially if you have multiple constructors and do not want to duplicate initialization.

Answer (score 0):

> And lastly, is this the norm in Java? to initialize variables outside the scope of constructors/methods

Actually this is just syntactic sugar which eliminates the need to repeat the same initialization in each costructor. When compiled, the initialization code will become a part of each constructor (except those which delegate to other constructors).